# Inner Product Space (Continuously Differentiable Functions)

Tags: calculus, integration, inner-products

Let $V=C^{2}[-\pi,\pi]$ be the space of real valued twice continuously differentiable functions defined on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$. Set $$\langle f,g \rangle=f(-\pi)g(-\pi)+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f''(x)g''(x)dx$$
Is this an inner product on $V$?

Comment: which properties should you verify to prove/disprove that?I mean, is the positive-definiteness which troubles you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the function

$$f(x)=x+\pi$$

belongs to $C^2([-\pi,\pi])$ and satisfies  $f(-\pi)=0$, $f^{''}(x)=0$ for all $x\in\left[-\pi,\pi\right]$. This implies $\langle f,f\rangle=0$.